# DeSerializing dynamic array in GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I am working on JSON response . I want to store JSON response in model then store the model values into DB.

So that I used GSON to parse the JSON response.

In my response I have some dynamic JSON array names. The sample and part of the response is below.

```
   {


      "TD": [
        {

          "TimeClockDetails": {
            "March 2, 2016": [
              {
                "TimeclockId": "148148",

              },
]
}
```

In that response , I have the ""March 2, 2016":" array . If a static array name means I can use `@SerializeName("arrayname_in_response")`.

Now, how can I deserialize this dynamic array name ?

If need more clarification,I am ready to provide.

Comment: You should have a serious conversation with whoever though using `March 2, 2016` for a json key was a good idea

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use a `Map`.

```
@SerializedName("TimeClockDetails")
private Map<String, TimeDetail> mTimeClockDetails;
```

This way the date keys would end as keys in the map.

Comment: Here I am working on your solution. Will let you know. :)

Comment: I am getting "Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY" error due to this. Any other solution ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVe use `TimeDetail[]` instead, or `List<TimeDetail>`